# Monitoring/Alerting On Log File Change In Windows

Tags: windows-server-2003

Does anyone know of a simple tool that will email me every time a new change is added to a log file?  I have an issue that I'd like to be notified of right away, but the only way I'd know if by monitoring this file.

I've seen a few tools that do this, but they're more geared towards running interactively on the desktop and notifying you that way, as opposed to running as a service on a server.  I've also seen file integrity checkers that are part of a tripwire/IDS, but it's usually part of a bigger suite.

I'm sure I could just write this in powershell, but I imagine there already is a simple tool like this out there and I just haven't found it yet.

Edit: To clarify, I'm speaking about a txt file, not windows logs.

Comment: What do you need to monitor specifically? In many cases the event viewer can be setup to monitor & send emails without the need for 3rd party solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Logstash can consume windows event logs, and can alert on them via a number of mechanisms (SMTP, XMPP, etc.)

http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/inputs/eventlog